# Elementos QML sobre a barra de status

Tags: android, ios, qml

Estou tendo um problema quando o teclado do dispositivo é mostrado. Os elementos ficam em cima da barra de status do dispositivo como nas imagens.

Eu já tentei usar o `Flickable` type mas não funciona. Toda vez que o teclado é mostrado ele empurra os componentes para cima da barra de status

OBS: O problema ocorre tanto no Android como no iOS.

Código:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    property int larguraTela: 360
    property int alturaTela: 640
    width: larguraTela
    height: alturaTela
    maximumWidth: larguraTela
    maximumHeight: alturaTela
    minimumWidth: larguraTela
    minimumHeight: alturaTela
    title: "OverStatusBar"

    Rectangle{
        id: retangulo1

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.5
        anchors.top: parent.top
        color: "grey"
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: retangulo2

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.5
        anchors.top: retangulo1.bottom
        color: "lightgrey"

        TextField {
            id: campoTexto

            width: parent.width * 0.7
            height: parent.height * 0.15
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Android 1] [image: Android 2]
[image: iOS 1] [image: iOS 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este comportamento foi aceito como bug pelo Qt. Pra quem quiser acompanhar aqui está o link.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50200